# A Tour of Go, problem #56 - error handling

Tags: go, error-handling

New to Go, trying to solve [Tour of Go, Exercise 56](http://tour.golang.org/#56), which is about error handling.

Can the following error handling method can be further improved?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("cannot Sqrt negative number: %f", float64(e))
}

func Sqrt(f float64) (float64, error) {
    if f > 0 {
        return math.Sqrt(f), nil
    } else {
        return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(f)
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

Comment: Minor point, but you don't need to wrap the `return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(f)` in an else block. The `go vet` tool would complain about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would name the error `ErrSqrtNegative` instead of `ErrNegativeSqrt`.

`Sqrt(0)` should not be an error.

In case of error, I would use `math.NaN(), ErrSqrtNegative(f)` as the return values.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the [exercise](http://tour.golang.org/#56) calls for the error to be named `ErrNegativeSqrt`.

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type ErrNegativeSqrt float64

func (e ErrNegativeSqrt) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("cannot Sqrt negative number: %g", e)
}

func Sqrt(f float64) (float64, error) {
    if f < 0 {
        return 0, ErrNegativeSqrt(f)
    }
    const delta = 1e-12
    z := f
    for {
        zz := z
        z -= (z*z - f) / (2 * z)
        if math.Abs(z-zz) < delta {
            break
        }
    }
    return z, nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(-2))
}
```

Output:

```
1.414213562373095 <nil>
0 cannot Sqrt negative number: -2
```

Comment: Code-only answers do not constitute a review. Please explain how your changes improve the original code.